# Which negative modifiers should I apply when transforming myself?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I'm running a witcheling, a changeling witch who, because of a GM's homebrew magic ring, can transform into a [pixie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/pixie).

What effects does this pixie transformation have? Specifically...

- Since I'm now Small, do I apply +1 to AC, +1 to attack rolls, –1 to CMB and CMD and +4 to Stealth?
- Am I able to cast spells while transformed?
- Do I lose my racial benefits while transformed?
- Am I still able to use weapons such as staff, longsword, or greatsword?

Comment: Welcome to site. Take the [tour]. The `help` and `?` buttons really work. What method is the character using to assume pixie form?

Comment: I use a magical ring gifted by the GM just in benefit of the role-playing. It doesn't improve anything, it only allows me to transform.

Comment: Afaik it only makes the character pixie-shaped

Comment: Don't worry. Its a normal Small Pixie or so I describe it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### The specific effects of changing size often depend upon how the size change occurred

A homebrew magic item's effects always work the way the GM says they work. That said, if a [changeling](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/uncommon-races/arg-changeling) [witch](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/witch) takes the form of [pixie](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/pixie) *via* the GM's homebrew magic item—assuming in pixie form the changeling can fly at speeds comparable to a typical pixie—, the magic item is likely using an effect like the spell [*beast shape II*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/beast-shape) except allowing a transformation into the shape of a creature with the [fey](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Fey) type.

Because this is a [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) effect, the Table: Ability Adjustments from Size Changes is used then the specific effects of the spell *beast shape II*, adjusting for the shape of a pixie.

- The effects of the spell *beast shape II* when used to transform into a Small *animal* include the transformed creature gaining a +2 size bonus to its Dexterity score and a +1 natural armor bonus. While pixie form makes the former seem reasonable, the latter may be suspect despite the pixie having a +1 natural armor bonus; ask the DM. The pixie possesses low-light vision and a 60-ft. fly speed with good maneuverability, so the spell's effect provides those as well.
- Despite the creature's pixie size and appearance, the creature keeps its racial abilities unless incompatible with the new form. (Again, see the description of [polymorph](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic#TOC-Transmutation) effects).
- A typical pixie can speak, wiggle fingers, and manipulate material components and foci, so casting spells in pixie form shouldn't be a problem, although it may be helpful to drop the spell components pouch and foci before the transformation (see below).
- Confirm the status of the creature's gear upon initiating the transformation. Without knowing on what spell the pixie transformation is based, the creature's equipment could *either* resize (cf. the spell [*reduce person*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/r/reduce-person)) *or* meld into the new form, limiting the creature's access to it while transformed, as is usual for a polymorph effect.
- A Small creature can employ light and 1-handed weapons designed for a Medium creature as 1-handed and 2-handed weapons, respectively, but the creature suffers a −2 penalty to attack rolls with such weapons.

  A Small creature can still employ a designed-for-a-Medium-creature *magic* staff's powers, but a Small creature can't beat up monsters with a staff designed for a Medium creature as the effort necessary for it to wield such a staff is too great.
- A Small creature applies the appropriate size modifier to Armor Class, CMD, CMB, and attack rolls. Further, a Small creature's ability to use some skills is sometimes improved (e.g. [Fly](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/fly), [Stealth](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/stealth)) and to use some skills is sometimes impaired (e.g. [Intimidate](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/skills/intimidate)). Finally, a Small creature has a different [carrying capacity](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/alignment-description/carrying-capacity) from a Medium creature.

Although easier than it was in *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5*, changing size is a complex process in *Pathfinder*. I've found it useful to have a whole second character sheet filled out for my resized character. I suggest you do the same once the specifics of the pixie transformation ability are confirmed.

Comment: Thanks, I couldnt find much information but now I got it clear. Ill talk to the GM and see how we manage this.